# Android -.net WCF Generated Service consumption

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

I have a test wcf service which I am trying to consume from a test android app.
New to Android and after much trial and error score is Android 1 me nil.

I have tried KSoap2.

Both from various tutorials and adapting the code  generated by the good website `http://www.wsdl2code.com/`

I have tried rolling my own SOAP Request both from tutorials and using the working soap request that xmlspy generates.

Could someone please try and consume the 'TestResponse' contract and post how they did it. It takes no parameters and returns a string 'Connection Succeeded'

The wsdl is:

```
http://www.adriley.co.nz:7500/testsvc/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

The XMLSpy Request is:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <m:TestResponse xmlns:m="http://tempuri.org/"/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Missed the SOAP. <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <m:TestResponse xmlns:m="http://tempuri.org/"/>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: Do you mean problem is solved?

Comment: No. When I posted the display stopped at 'The XMLSpyRequest is:. Came back later and it was showing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have proven (I think) that it is a KSOAP2 issue with WCF. I moved onto consuming the production webservice which is an asmx and it all worked. So unless I am wrong I don't think anyone has used KSOAP2 to consume a WCF Webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to consume TestResponse service with following values:

- URL : http://www.adriley.co.nz:7500/testsvc/Service1.svc (Use without ?wsdl)
- Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
- SoapAction : http://tempuri.org/IService1/TestResponse
- Method: TestResponse

SoapAction is extracted from here:

```
<wsdl:operation name="TestResponse">
 <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/TestResponse" style="document"/>
...
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Kerim,Once I read your response properly I was able to get a connection. Thanks